# Call await method from a method with ref pameters?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, ref

I need to call a `await` method from [`NavigateError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268221(v=vs.85).aspx) event, whose the signature (see below) I can't change:

```
void instance_NavigateError(object pDisp, ref object URL, ref object Frame, ref object StatusCode, ref bool Cancel);
```

Marking it as `async` so I would do:

```
await myMethod(foo);
```

Give the error:

> Error CS1988  Async methods cannot have ref or out parameters

How can I workaround this?

Comment: Your question is "I need to do something impossible; how do I do it?" You don't. Either you don't *need* to await, or you don't *need* to have refs. If you need both, then you *need* to learn how to live with the disappointment of not getting your needs met.

Comment: is there a reason you are using the ActiveX component and not the [Winforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) component?

Comment: @EricLippert: I was looking for a workaround, if any. If I was so sure it was impossible, I would not ask because I'm that stupid.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I'm using WinForms' webBrowser but that event, as far I know, is not exposed directly, so I need to access the ActiveX instance to get access to that event. It's a way to catch the WebBrowser control loading page errors.

Comment: So you have method with ref whose signature you cannot change. Only "workaround" left - don't make it async and don't await inside it. If you insist you have to await - you need to provide some arguments (like what exactly you are trying to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this using async/await. Using ref/out in an async method would not make sense because of how async methods work.

You did not specify the signature of `myMethod`, so the example below assumes you need the return value of the async method. If you don't need to wait for the method to finish, you can just call it like a normal method: `myMethod(foo)`. Do note that any exceptions that are thrown in `myMethod` will be ignored.

A workaround would be to manually type out the .ContinueWith. Because this requires the use of a lambda (or a seperate method) you will not be able to set the ref parameters after this call.

```
private void instance_NavigateError(object pDisp, ref object URL, ref object Frame, ref object StatusCode, ref bool Cancel)
{
    myMethod(foo).ContinueWith(t => {
        var resultOfMethod = t.Result;

        // Do something with resultOfMethod
    });
}
```

You can read the ref parameters by placing them in a variable first

```
private void instance_NavigateError(object pDisp, ref object URLref, ref object Frame, ref object StatusCode, ref bool Cancel)
{
    var URL = URLref;
    myMethod(foo).ContinueWith(t => {
        var resultOfMethod = t.Result;

        // Do something with resultOfMethod and URL
    });
}
```

Comment: `ContinueWith()` seems really the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: @Jack: Hold up a minute here: you said that you needed to await. An await is a point in the workflow where the workflow *must* suspend *until the awaited result is available*. `ContinueWith` signs up the continuation, and we know that the continuation does not activate until the task is complete, but if you need the *handler* to suspend *its* work until the task is complete, you have *not* achieved that goal. (Because it is *impossible*.)